# Moodle - terms of agreement activity

Tags: moodle

I'm creating a moodle site for school students with couple courses.

When they start the course, I want to have a page like terms of agreement with a check box. The students should be able to proceed with the lessons only after agreeing to the terms.

Is there something that could do this?

Answer (score 1):

Moodle can do this for users when they first log in if you set the site policy URL (under Site Administration -> Security -> Site policies). If you wanted them to accept the terms for each course then you'd have to do something custom. Perhaps a Lesson module where access to the rest of the lesson depends on viewing the terms of agreement?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single question quiz, in every course. THis quiz has answers agree or dont agree. If the student agrees then award him 100% marks.

For every other lesson/exam in these courses use Conditional activities. (This is the official documentation page http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Conditional_activities)

What conditional activities do is enable teachers to restrict the availability a course section (in Moodle 2.3 onwards) according to certain conditions such as dates, grade obtained, or activity completion.

Use grade obtained in first quiz as condition to access further sections.